# I'm looking for this graph solution

Tags: graph

Recently I found a pretty graph when I was browsing the adminskins at ThemeForest and in one of the templates I found a really nice, smooth, clean graph. But I've searching arround but so far without luck finding out which solution is used.

And example can be found at:
http://enstyled.com/adminus/original/page.html

The source of this graph looks like:

```
<table class="stats bar" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <th scope="col">02.09</th>
                            <th scope="col">03.09</th>
                            <th scope="col">04.09</th>
                            <th scope="col">05.09</th>
                            <th scope="col">06.09</th>
                            <th scope="col">07.09</th>
                            <th scope="col">08.09</th>
                            <th scope="col">09.09</th>
                            <th scope="col">10.09</th>
                            <th scope="col">11.09</th>
                            <th scope="col">12.09</th>
                            <th scope="col">01.10</th>
                            <th scope="col">02.10</th>
                            <th scope="col">03.10</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">Page views</th>
                            <td>1800</td>
                            <td>900</td>
                            <td>700</td>
                            <td>1200</td>
                            <td>600</td>
                            <td>2800</td>
                            <td>3200</td>
                            <td>500</td>
                            <td>2200</td>
                            <td>1000</td>
                            <td>1200</td>
                            <td>700</td>
                            <td>650</td>
                            <td>800</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">Unique visitors</th>                                
                            <td>1600</td>
                            <td>650</td>
                            <td>550</td>
                            <td>900</td>
                            <td>500</td>
                            <td>2300</td>
                            <td>2700</td>
                            <td>350</td>
                            <td>1700</td>
                            <td>600</td>
                            <td>1000</td>
                            <td>500</td>
                            <td>400</td>
                            <td>700</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Can someone please tell me which graphingsolution is used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page is just drawing lines in a canvas tag.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Now I understand why they included excanvas.js in their source ;)

Answer (score 1):

In that page they are using jquery and you can use **[Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)** which is a graph plugin in jquery.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've seen Flot before (when Googling ;)), it looks pretty promising. I'll give it a try!